# How to set UI table view first cell on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

in my application **i have a table view and a segment with three buttons,**

*each button action populates different arrays in the same table  and reloads every time,*

when i was in 3rd segment and when i scrolls the table filled with coresponding 3rd segment data,

and return bak to the 1st, 2nd segments wiht their respective data , the content on these other segments also scrolls,

**My requirement is for each segment click table view, first cell set to top every time**

I tried with `setScrollToTop` and `setPagingEnable` but no use,

```
[contactsTable setPagingEnabled:YES];
[contactsTable setScrollToTop:YES];
```

**How to set the table view first cell always on top when segment clicked and when view appears, irrespective of previous step scrolling...?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
[contactsTable setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
```

Comment: Or use `[contactsTable setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[contactsTable selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [contactsTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[contactsTable indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```